# How to recieve the file from swagger fileupload to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger UI file upload doesn't work, gives undefined values.

I tried the code below, but when I already try to choose file, and execute it
all the `req.body`, `req.files` or so are just gives undefined.
Can you lead me to right direction?
I need to upload the data, from swagger to a folder in nodejs app.

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Multer middleware setup for file uploads
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const uploads = multer({ dest: __dirname + "/uploads" });

// Define the Swagger options
const swaggerOptions = {
  definition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'File Upload API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
  },
  apis: ['./app.js'], // Point to the current file for Swagger annotations
};

// Initialize Swagger-jsdoc
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);

// Serve Swagger UI
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpec));

// Serve static files (e.g., HTML forms)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/**
 * @swagger
 * /upload:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Upload a file.
 *     consumes:
 *       - multipart/form-data
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: formData
 *         name: file
 *         schema:
 *            type: file
 *         type: file
 *         required: true
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: File uploaded successfully.
 */
app.post('/upload', uploads.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)
    console.log(req.file)
    const uploadedFile = req.file
  if (!uploadedFile) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded.' });
  }
  // Handle the uploaded file, e.g., save it or process it.
  // For this example, we are just sending back a success message.
  res.json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully' });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

[image]
[image]